# Unable to connect to laptop's localhost from mobile using Nginx or XAMPP

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, html

I've just installed Nginx 1.16.0 on my windows 10.

It works when I browse my local machine for my website. For example when I type localhost/view.html in chrome.

However, when I try to do this on my android phone, it doesn't work.

What i've tried:

1. Used local machines IP instead of "localhost" on my android's browser.
2. Both devices are in the same WiFi network.
3. Adding an exception rule in Bitdefender's firewall for Nginx.exe
4. WiFi is selected as a private/home network
   downloaded XAMPP and still the same scenario.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

What do I need to do to view my website on my phone?

P.S. This is for an assignment and I NEED to use Nginx only. Also, my WiFi is similar to a hotel Wifi where i have a username and password to sign in and start using the internet.

Comment: localhost (127.0.0.1) does not go outside the device, it connects only locally.

Comment: *"My WiFi is similar to a hotel Wifi where I have a username and password[.]"* -- Do you even have access to or control over the router?

Comment: @Anaksunaman no I don't believe I can access the router's configuration page. 
Anyway, I've figured out a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out the solution.

What I've done is:

1. Connect my laptop to the WiFi.
2. Turn on my laptop's hotspot / Internet Sharing
3. Connect my phone to my laptop's hotspot.

And voila, it works.